# raspbianでpiユーザを削除できない。

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian

raspbianで新しいユーザ(newuser)を作り`sudo userdel -r pi`をしましたが削除できません。

エラー

`userdel: user pi is currently used by process 585`

そこで`sudo kill 585`を実行し、piとkillしましたがその後削除コマンドを実行すると

`userdel: user pi is currently used by process 596`となり削除できません。

whoコマンドの結果は以下のとおりです。

```html
pi       :0           2015-09-30 00:33 (:0)
pi       tty1         2015-09-30 00:33
newuser   pts/0        2015-09-30 00:33 (192.168.0.10)
```

どうすればpiユーザを削除することができるのでしょうか

Comment: pi ユーザがログインしたままですので、全てログアウトする必要があるのではないでしょうか。X も起動されている様ですので、一旦 single user mode で再起動してから削除した方が良いかも知れません。

Comment: アドバイスを参考にしてraspi-configのBoot OptionsをConsoleにしたところ、piユーザで起動しなくなりました。どうやら、起動時にX Windowにpiユーザでログインする設定になっていたようです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

アドバイスを参考にして `raspi-config` の "Boot Options" を "Console" にしたところ、pi ユーザで起動しなくなりました。どうやら、起動時にX Windowに pi ユーザでログインする設定になっていたようです。

---

*この投稿は [@StackDestroyer さんのコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/17070/raspbian%e3%81%a7pi%e3%83%a6%e3%83%bc%e3%82%b6%e3%82%92%e5%89%8a%e9%99%a4%e3%81%a7%e3%81%8d%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84#comment15595_17070) の内容を元に コミュニティwiki として投稿しました。*